# libreoffice re-type password

Tags: libreoffice

I've just upgraded to Libreoffice 3.6.3 from 3.5.7 due to a bug, it fixed the bug but presented a new problem. When I save my ODS spreadsheet with many password protected sheets (20) to an Excel spreadsheet I'm presented with a dialogue box to Re-type Passwords for every protected sheet.

I have many of these spreadsheets is there an easier way to fix this problem or will I have to re-type passwords many times to fix this?[image: Re-type password dialogue]

---

I am having this problem as well, LO version "3.5.6.2".

I have the original documents saved as ".xls". So in theory, this should not be an issue at all. However, the end users love to make straight forward processes more complicated than is necessary, so here I am.

I did some testing: I can save my file (with protected sheet) as a ".ods" file, THEN save it to ".xls" format without issue. IF, however, I close LO after saving the file as ods, and then open LO and the ods file AGAIN, and attempt to save as xls, it fails with the error the OP has described: "Hash incompatible".

Something is being lost when Libre closes that is necessary for ODS files to be saved with password protected sheets.

EDIT:

When prompted, if you elect to "re-type", you actually get presented with several options. One option is to save without the password. However, the other option allows you to retype WITHOUT verifying a match. I used this option, and after that, the status message changed from "Hash incompatible" to "Hash compatible". I saved the document as ".xls" type, then closed Calc.

I then opened calc, and saved it as ".ods". Closed calc again. Opened the ".ods" file, and attempted to save as ".xls". Would you like to overwrite? Yes I would! And I got the password retype message again.

So, however the hash was saved the first time I retyped the password (overwriting the old hash?), it was not saved correctly because the hash was incorrect upon the same process a second time.

Comment: This is a very specific question, it will be difficult finding someone here that knows a solution, haven't you tried asking this in LibreOffice Forum ( http://libreofficeforum.org/ ) ?

Comment: You should submit a brain storm feature request to LO